# MS Access Autonumber dilemma

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-server

I am using a sql query that will copy the data from one table to another.

The problem though is the counter which I put in the Second table of my Insert into Select Statement.

It all started from the last count from the first table meaning the first table has 2000 as I insert it to second table the autonumber column of it started in 2000 not 1.

How should I reset it?

Comment: It is likely there have been no comments or answers to this because you have not shown an effort to resolve this yourself. Below is my simple answer to get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many resources to research this topic. Searching the Internet for `access reset autonumber`, the first things that comes up is this Microsoft Support article - [How to reset an AutoNumber field value in Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718).

I've used this method successfully in the past. Remember...BACKUP, BACKUP, BACKUP!!